# C# Unity rotating Point A so child of point A with a fixed offset keeps that offset, all in world space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, offset, quaternions

Im setting up a Leg IK system, using world space positions to set the targetPos for each foot.
This works great but the problem is that when the parent is rotated, the targetPositions for each foot are kept in world space so the feet will stay in place while the parent turns.

See these pictures:

Correct feet placement:

[image]

And Incorrect feet placement after turning parent Y axis to 180degrees:
[image]

I think I need to find the new worldPosition for each foot based on their offset from the parent? I have no idea how to approach this and I couldnt find the question anywhere else(probably due to incorrect terminology, it is what it is.)

What I have right now is just a lot of trial and error, and I got it working pretty smoothly without using the real mathematics to actually solve this without approximations by hand like I did.
But that is pretty bad code, so can someone tell me how I can do this using C#/Unity ?

Its an IK Leg rig, each leg IK has its own target position, which it will go to when the command is given. So I will just "rotate" the target for each foot around, while I also rotate the main body.
Problem is all footTarget positions are in World Space and do not rotate with the parent object, like you can see in the pictures.

Heres my solution code with approximations(just trying to imagine where feet would go when the player rotates, and then setting them there manually while the body(parent) is rotating.

```
 private void Start()
{
    footSpacing = transform.position.x;
    currentPosition = newPosition = oldPosition = targetPos = transform.position;
    currentNormal = newNormal = oldNormal = transform.up;
    lerp = 1;

    StartCoroutine("LerpCycle");

}
void Update()
{
    transform.position = currentPosition;
    transform.up = currentNormal;
}

public void RotateR()
{
    if (rightLeg)
    {
        targetPos -= (body.right * (stepLength * .2f));
        targetPos -= (body.forward * (stepLength * .2f));
    }
    else
    {
        targetPos += (body.right * (stepLength * .35f));
        //targetPos += (body.forward * (stepLength * f));
    }
    RayToNewPos();
}
public void RotateL()
{

}

void RayToNewPos()
{
    Ray ray = new Ray(Vector3.up * 2f + targetPos, Vector3.down);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit info, 10, terrainLayer.value))
    {

        if (!stepping)
        {
            stepping = true;
            delayed = false;
        }

        lerp = 0;

        newPosition = targetPos;
        //.223f

        if (newPosition.y < .224f) newPosition.y = .223f; // Make sure foot never goes below ground

        newNormal = info.normal;


    }
}





IEnumerator LerpCycle()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (lerp < 1)
        {
            if (!rightLeg)
            {
                Vector3 tempPosition = Vector3.Lerp(oldPosition, newPosition, lerp);
                tempPosition.y += Mathf.Sin(lerp * Mathf.PI) * stepHeight;

                currentPosition = tempPosition;
                currentNormal = Vector3.Lerp(oldNormal, newNormal, lerp);
                lerp += Time.deltaTime * speed;
            }
            else
            {
                //if (!delayed)
                //{
                //    delayed = true;
                //    yield return new WaitForSeconds(rightFootDelay);
                //}
                Vector3 tempPosition = Vector3.Lerp(oldPosition, newPosition, lerp);
                tempPosition.y += Mathf.Sin(lerp * Mathf.PI) * stepHeight;

                currentPosition = tempPosition;
                currentNormal = Vector3.Lerp(oldNormal, newNormal, lerp);
                lerp += Time.deltaTime * speed;
            }
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
        else oldPosition = newPosition;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I have all values set in stone, say I want to rotate 45 degrees per RotateR command instead of the value of 30 that I have now. It will break the whole animation.
So what I really need is a mathematical way to define what the real position of the 2 children should be at ***any given angle.***

Thank you!

Comment: For anyone having this question I think the answer is this:

'offsetDefault = transform.position - body.position;' and
        'offsetPos = Quaternion.Inverse(body.rotation) * offsetDefault;' in 'Start()'

Then get the new position for the child this is on:
'newBodyRot.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, StepMovement.instance.rotateAngle, 0);'
'var calculatedPos = newBodyRot * offsetPos + newBodyPos;'

Also its possible to create empty game objects, child them to main body that rotates, and keep their Transform store as a static target that rotates with the body, thats the eaisest way.

Comment: Consider [self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)